# cherry picking a commit that deletes files

Tags: git

I need to merge several repositories (each of them was converted from [TFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server)) into one. To do that I use git cherry-pick command, which works for some commits, but not for others:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r e2d8405
Libraries/IFileTransformer/ITransformer.cs
Libraries/IFileTransformer/IFileTransformer.csproj
Libraries/IFileTransformer/IFileTransformer.csproj.vspscc
Libraries/IFileTransformer/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
$ git cherry-pick e2d8405
error: could not apply e2d8405... TFS changeset 2836
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
$ git status
# On branch master
# You are currently cherry-picking.
#   (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#       deleted by them:    Libraries/IFileTransformer/ITransformer.cs
#       deleted by them:    Libraries/IFileTransformer/IFileTransformer.csproj
#       deleted by them:    Libraries/IFileTransformer/IFileTransformer.csproj.vspscc
#       deleted by them:    Libraries/IFileTransformer/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$
```

How do I find out what is wrong here? Who is "them"? It seems to me that the e2d8405 commit deletes the four files. If the files exist (and they do) then where is the problem with applying the commit?

```
$ git checkout e2d8405^
Note: checking out 'e2d8405^'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at 48b5b2f... TFS changeset 2835   renamed namespace installutils to
 utils
$ md5sum IFileTransformer.csproj
9f9851dc9db3bddd1e6920631fa14e8b *IFileTransformer.csproj
$ git checkout master
Previous HEAD position was 48b5b2f... TFS changeset 2835   renamed namespace ins
tallutils to utils
Switched to branch 'master'
$ md5sum IFileTransformer.csproj
9f9851dc9db3bddd1e6920631fa14e8b *IFileTransformer.csproj
```

Comment: "Them" is the commit you're cherry-picking. "Us" is the branch you're cherry-picking onto.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I suspected: the commit deletes the four files. But where is the problem with that operation...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although that commit deletes those files, you have modifications that weren't present in the deleted version. As there is a conflict here, between the branch that modifies the files and the branch that deletes them, you will need to resolve it by indicating that you're happy to discard the changes and apply the delete (`git rm ...`). Once you've done that, `git commit` to create the cherry-picked commit.

Comment: How can I find out what these changes were? It seems to me that the files on master and on preceeding commit are the same (added commands and results that show it to the question).

Comment: There's a chance that checking them out discards whitespace changes. Try `git diff HEAD e2d8405^ Libraries/IFileTransformer/ITransformer.cs Libraries/IFileTransformer/IFileTransformer.csproj Libraries/IFileTransformer/IFileTransformer.csproj.vspscc Libraries/IFileTransformer/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs` or, alternatively, `git log -p HEAD...e2d8405^ <same files>` to see commits.

Comment: Indeed the line endings were different in those files.

Comment: Ok, now I know what is wrong, but how do I actually fix this? How do I make the cherry-picking ignore whitespace differences?

Answer (score 1):

Run `git mergetool` it will tell you why it's seeing a conflict for deleted files the file was likely changed locally AND deleted in the cherry-picked "them" commit. It wants you to decide if you want to keep the modified version or delete the files.

You can then  select the action you want to take on these files.

Answer (score 0):

The way git merging works is something like this:

For each file to merge, find the newest commit that includes the and exists in both the branches that are to be merged. Then search through each of the branches to be merged and look for any subsequent change, changes that then will be present in just one of the branches.

- If there are no such change in either branch, leave the file untouched
- If one of the branches has changes to the file, and the other doesn't, keep the one with changes
- If both branches have changes, then git can not automerge (which of the changes should be kept, which should be discarded - impossible to say without manual intervention)

What you have is a case of the last of these, where the file is deleted in one branch, but has been changed in the other branch, after the last time the two branches were merged.

```
  A 1* B
   / \
  2   3
  |   |
  |   4*
  5*  |
  |   |
```

Here, the numbers are commits, and the * indicates that the commit change a file that we are interested in is included in the commit. So, at commit 1 we haven't yet branched out, which means that this commit is the base commit, the newest commit that is present in both branches. After the branching, a commit is added to each of the branches, but neither includes the file in question. When merging at this point, the file just stays as it was in commit 1. Then at commit 4, a change is made to the file in branch B. If we were to merge branch B into branch A at this point, the changes made to the file in commit 4 will be merged into branch A, since it's the newest commit and there are no changes to the file in branch A after the base commit (1). But then at commit 5, the file is changed in branch A as well. Now if we try to merge (either way will produce same result), we will get a conflict, since the file has been changed in both branches (after the base commit), and git is unable to select one of the as being 'correct', thus leaving it up to you to decide.

Check the file history of the files in the branch that doesn't include the delete, then you might discover a commit that is in this branch, and not the branch where they were deleted.

Comment: An automerge is the application of a three way merge algorithm on two files that differ and their common ancestor, used to merge line by line changes.  It is used when both branches have changed.  Manual intervention is only necessary if automerge fails to produce output.  Automerge is wholly unnecessary if only one side changed.