# Could not apply patches for qemuarm (linux-yocto), Could not update git tree

Tags: git, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to build a core-image-minimal

```
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.24.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "Fedora-21"
TARGET_SYS        = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE           = "qemuarm"
DISTRO            = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "1.7.1"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "arm armv5 thumb dsp"
TARGET_FPU        = "soft"
meta              
meta-yocto        
meta-yocto-bsp    = "dizzy:c59e3bd26d863723af7ba5e16570b091ef7cdc13"
```

I did a git pull and got the same problem with this version:

```
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.24.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "Fedora-21"
TARGET_SYS        = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE           = "qemuarm"
DISTRO            = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "1.7.2"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "arm armv5 thumb dsp"
TARGET_FPU        = "soft"
meta              
meta-yocto        
meta-yocto-bsp    = "dizzy:9fd145d27ec479668fac490a9f1078089f22bf59"
```

and I always have this error:

```
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_patch
| Deleted branch meta-temp (was d36a7ef).
| [INFO] validating against known patches  (qemuarm-standard-meta)
ERROR. could not update git tree##################   ] (\)(94 %))
| ERROR: Could not apply patches for qemuarm.
| ERROR: Patch failures can be resolved in the devshell (bitbake -c devshell linux-yocto)
```

I tried to use "bitbake -c devshell linux-yocto", but it end up with the same error, before I get a shell.

I don't see how to debug this issue.

Comment: You could always try with `bitbake linux-yocto -c cleansstate` to see if that helps (by rebuilding the kernel from scratch). If that doesn't help you, could you extend the "Build configuration" that you pasted above, to also include all used layers and their SAH1? (This is printed just after the info above, when you invoke bitbake)

Comment: I already tried cleansstate, as well as removing the tmp folder.

`meta              
meta-yocto        
meta-yocto-bsp    = "dizzy:c59e3bd26d863723af7ba5e16570b091ef7cdc13"
`

Comment: Hm, I've just tried with your latest pull, `"dizzy:9fd145d27ec479668fac490a9f1078089f22bf59"` (as well as todays   HEAD, which is 2 commits later); and `bitbake virtual/kernel` builds just fine. Could you check with a fresh poky-clone (without reusing tmp and sstate-cache?) If that still doesn't work for you, we migth have to spin up a F21-box to check it on. (Sofar, I've done my tests on OpenSuse).

Comment: I removed all tmp and sstate. I still have the same error.
I also tried with the 1.8 "fido" branch: same issue "fido:59e4f9fc1255b7888ffccc87ce6cc3f2b8bf98c3"    Also I don't understand why devshell doesn't work

Comment: I have been able to build "core-image-minimal".
It worked with fido 1.8.
I will make other tests

Answer (score 0):

I've spend a lot of time on this problem myself when I had the following returned:

```
error: could not apply zp39187... my message
When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
```

It seems to happen because (in my case) commit 'zp39187' is causing a conflict  .

The general idea is to fix the conflict OR skip it by using:

```
git rebase --skip
```

The error however also seems to turn up while cherry-picking.

It might be useful to look at [cherry picking a commit that deletes files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923544), which helped me back then.